# Hook form upload

Tags: 7, files, javascript

I need to show a modal message like "Uploaded file exceeds X MB" when the user tries to upload a large file.
I have set maximum size in the field settings and when I try to upload a large file Drupal shows a label with custom error.
I need to trap this event and launch the `js` with modal message.

I have a;

```
 function hook_file_validate($file) {

     ....
 }
```

It is invoked in ajax so I cannot make a `drupal_add_js` call with the javascript code to execute.
How can I execute JS method for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting to do file size upload validation with complicated method of server/client code. If all you need is size validation, you can do that client-side without the need of the server.

There are many ways to do this; one example would involve adding a JS `onchange` event handler to your file field.

```
MYMODLE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id = "my_form") {
    $form['field_MYFILEFIELD']['#attributes']['onchange'] = "
      if (event.srcElement.files[0].size > (8 * 1048576)) { 
        alert('Uploaded file exceeds 8 MB'); 
        jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery(this).clone()); 
        return false;  
      }";
  }
  //@TODO: move the validation code to a function & use better modal
}
```